# How to convert interface to mapped type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

### Background

In the [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) for mapped types the following example is given:

```
type Proxy<T> = {
    get(): T;
    set(value: T): void;
}

type Proxify<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: Proxy<T[P]>;
}

function proxify<T>(o: T): Proxify<T> {
    // ... wrap proxies ...
}

let proxyProps = proxify(props);
```

It is unclear to me how I would write the proxify function.

### What I need it for

I have the following types

```
interface User extends BaseRecord {
    readonly 'id': number;
    readonly 'name'?: string;
}

interface FormField<T> {
    readonly value: T;
    readonly edited: boolean;
}

type WrappedInFormField<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: FormField<T[P]>;
};
```

And I need to write a function with the following signature

```
const wrap = <T>(o: T): WrappedInFormField<T> => {
    // ...What goes here?...
}

wrappedUser: WrappedInFormField<User> = wrap<User>(UserIJustGotFromApi);
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to just build up the object. Typescript will offer no help in creating mapped types, you just build them up as you normally would in Javascript.

```
const wrap = <T>(o: T): WrappedInFormField<T> => {
    // Create an empty object that we will add the properties to, assert it will be a WrappedInFormField<T> once we are done with it
    let result = {} as WrappedInFormField<T>;
    // Get all the keys of the original object
    for(var key in Object.keys(o)) { 
        // Create something compatible with FormField
        // You could instantiate a class, but you will not have access to the type of each property,
        // you could use any instead (for example if FormField<T> is a class you could just call new FormField<any> since types are erased it will not really matter)
        result[key] = {
            value: o[key],
            edited: false
        };
    }
    // return the result
    return  result;
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, that clears up my misunderstanding from the documentation - thank you. I changed a few things to make it compatible with the react-create-app Tslint configuration (const instead of var, entries instead of keys).