# Create object of mapped type with a constraint

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49364282/how-to-convert-interface-to-mapped-type-in-typescript) question I'm trying to create an object of a mapped type. However, I keep getting type errors in the implementation.

Here's a toy example:

```
type SingleArgFunction<A> = (x: A) => A;

type ArrayedReturnFunction<A> = (x: A) => A[];

// create an arrayed function from a single arg function

type MakeArrayed<F> = F extends SingleArgFunction<infer A> ? ArrayedReturnFunction<A> : never;

// mapped type

type MakeArrayedAll<FS> = {
    [K in keyof FS]: MakeArrayed<FS[K]>
}

// example usage

type MyFunctions = {
    foo: SingleArgFunction<number>,
    bar: SingleArgFunction<string>
}

type MyArrayedFunctions = MakeArrayedAll<MyFunctions> // ok

// functions to convert an object of single arg functions to object of arrayed functions

interface SingleArgFunctionObject {
    [key: string]: SingleArgFunction<any>
}

function makeArrayed<A>(f: SingleArgFunction<A>): ArrayedReturnFunction<A> {
    return function (x) {
        return [f(x)];
    }
}

function makeArrayedAll<FS extends SingleArgFunctionObject>(fs: FS): MakeArrayedAll<FS> {
    const keys = Object.keys(fs) as (keyof FS)[];
    const result = {} as MakeArrayedAll<FS>;

    for (let key of keys) {
        result[key] = makeArrayed(fs[key]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

This gives the following type error for `result`:

```
const result: MakeArrayedAll<FS>
Type 'ArrayedReturnFunction<any>' is not assignable to type 'MakeArrayed<FS[keyof FS]>'.(2322)
```

The difference with the previous question is that the properties of the unmapped type `FS` need to be constrained via `FS extends SingleArgFunctionObject`. Is there a solution other than asserting `result as any`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIEEBOSBiBXBAY2DgHsEAedAPigF4oAKADwC4p0BKe29AbgBQA0JA6ZMAQxAQAJgCUIwPJgT4iJclVoMW7Ljw4BtALqCBAenNRCmCBODQJCKBPFTZUAGYFiZZ58xSAFsXKABnRFRHbC8fDQQhEWgAWQkAaww3aRkKHG0oHCgIZgcEGTDYSLQsXDi-CkRPCEwOWgB+MUlshSUVNV9NGih2BAgAN2azSyggiTBIGSgkxPAU9Myu2XQUFFyYfIBvASgTqEMAaShEKAyQUk8CmGN2VIysTZycGAvjagEAXyE02KEiCYDQUDwYQkSAgK1EyRA-XiFQYR1OXlIpHY8GQ1WwyPqCDwQQARs1qAAaY6nUmuHFVTK1dT1MLATCRP6A4SrKCI97uGSE8iovnrAXZba7RHChBhWjTUhpIFWbwskVLUjWcgTTDAFzOUikgBWEGIUHu4UZLhiaoGcs1FpNZv1ltcH1i6rlQkQDkwngkhGguKiNVlAHlneb0adDLd2GyOchnpU8UzZRQnCAuUI7fEZuKsrItIxPAy02G6oNqJw9EX5IplKoq5QhjGTrZev4W0xmNx2xioJ2m2dPCxOKYaSdAdy834C2961K9kUShAyhUQ-jmfbI6biNRS2F2F9a2LFx9l19aAPCCL9bdRXuXQA6R9H7gSCqMW6W08mQQMTvOV9VsMI8BQfU0X+FwKleDZBSvfYzAxTxSBaRg0AfCAQAtB5H37KdBzAiDgDjHDjHoBcEOyI9yJAYxOEA05uQxYcVCHCBwMgwR-iAA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be inclined to refactor your types so as to avoid conditional types (which are hard for the compiler to reason about) and instead use mapped types and inference from mapped types as much as possible.  Your `makeArrayed()` function looks fine to me as-is.

I'll define `SingleArgFunctionObject` and `ArrayedReturnFunctionObject` to be generic in the object type `AS` that it maps over... the idea is that each property of `AS` is treated like the `A` in your `SingleArgFunction<A>` and `ArrayedReturnFunction<A>`:

```
type SingleArgFunctionObject<AS extends object> = {
    [K in keyof AS]: SingleArgFunction<AS[K]>
}

type ArrayedReturnFunctionObject<AS extends object> = {
    [K in keyof AS]: ArrayedReturnFunction<AS[K]>
}
```

Armed with this, `makeArrayedAll()` will be generic in `AS`.  The tricky bit for getting the compiler not to complain is to make the `for` loop treat each `key` as a generic `K extends keyof AS`.  That's easier to do with the `forEach()` method of arrays:

```
function makeArrayedAll<AS extends object>(
    fs: SingleArgFunctionObject<AS>
): ArrayedReturnFunctionObject<AS> {
    const result = {} as ArrayedReturnFunctionObject<AS>;
    (Object.keys(fs) as (keyof AS)[]).forEach(<K extends keyof AS>(key: K) => {
        result[key] = makeArrayed(fs[key]);
    })
    return result;
}
```

That should produce the same result as your code, but now the compiler is more confident that `makeArrayed(fs[key])` of type `ArrayedReturnFunction<AS[K]>` is assignable to `result[key]` of type `ArrayedReturnFunctionObject<AS>[K]`.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAyglgOwOYBsIEEBOSBiBXBAY2DgHsEAedAPigF4oAKADwC4p0BKe29AbgBQoSB0yYAhiAgATAEoRgeTAnxES5KrQYt2XHhwDaAXUEAzAsTIIoAW3EBrDGMkzNjU+3jI0WXBfWUNJy6zlJyCkoq-laaUADeAlBJUJgRylDmalZMzNwJyQUpadYGpiycJonJAL4CtULg0F6oTn5Z5ADyAEYAVhDEVDBQEMzAEAjSAM5QpL39wFrxVUkGANJQiFCOIKSmHDBGnogtvqqWGugwa0bUdQINIlgSYfKKymcB3X0Dl8Oj41MZnNiIt8sk1htrNtdvtDqJnjJXpEPjFLtdbvVMudrHZHE8XNJ0CgUIM-mMJtNZt8FoxlhlJkdvK0UZ1gcBBrdgvCCUj3tFWdSOUsCoRyJNgEVJngUBKGHFqlBxNN8S9iiyEF95hzBAVGJriAA6baTdyTbhKpjQvaXTjGTgG0ykTAAUXEhAAFowKOsRuTAVb9tRGNt2KtuHRaGDCpLpcADNsjPRbA4nAjpKb4xAQEZODqapw6ak3tZUlKZYJ6kA)

Comment: Thank you very much! Whilst there is plenty of information in the typescript docs about mapped types, there is rather less about creating objects of those types. Would be great to see more stuff like this.