# Inferring generic 'this' type

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

Following on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895071/374328) question, I am now trying to create functions with an explicit [this parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) of a type extending interface `IModel`:

```
// interface for Model class

interface IModel {
    state: {}
}

// based on answer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895071/374328
// now functions will be bound to model instance, so need to specify 'this' parameter as Model

type SingleArgFunction<Model extends IModel, A> = (this: Model, x: A) => A;
type ArrayedReturnFunction<Model extends IModel, A> = (this: Model, x: A) => A[];

type SingleArgFunctionObject<Model extends IModel, AS extends object> = {
    [K in keyof AS]: SingleArgFunction<Model, AS[K]>
}

type ArrayedReturnFunctionObject<Model extends IModel, AS extends object> = {
    [K in keyof AS]: ArrayedReturnFunction<Model, AS[K]>
}

function makeArrayed<Model extends IModel, A>(f: SingleArgFunction<Model, A>): ArrayedReturnFunction<Model, A> {
    return function (x) {
        return [f.call(this, x)];
    }
}

function makeArrayedAll<Model extends IModel, AS extends object>(
    fs: SingleArgFunctionObject<Model, AS>
): ArrayedReturnFunctionObject<Model, AS> {
    const result = {} as ArrayedReturnFunctionObject<Model, AS>;

    (Object.keys(fs) as (keyof AS)[]).forEach(function<K extends keyof AS>(key: K) {
        result[key] = makeArrayed(fs[key]);
    })
    return result;
}
```

An example model and type definitions:

```
interface MyModel extends IModel {
    state: {
        x: number;
    }
}

interface SingleArgFunctions {
    foo: SingleArgFunction<MyModel, number>
}

interface ArrayedReturnFunctions {
    foo: ArrayedReturnFunction<MyModel, number>;
}
```

Creating an object of `ArrayedReturnFunctions` directly is ok, with `this` being inferred as type `MyModel`:

```
const arrayedReturnFunctions1: ArrayedReturnFunctions = {
    foo(x) {
        return [x + this.state.x]; // ok
    }
}
```

Alternatively, creating the object by applying `makeArrayed` to a single function is also ok:

```
const arrayedReturnFunctions2: ArrayedReturnFunctions = {
    foo: makeArrayed(function (x) {
        return x + this.state.x; // ok
    })
}
```

However, using `makeArrayedAll` does not work - `this` is inferred as type `IModel`:

```
const arrayedReturnFunctions3: ArrayedReturnFunctions = makeArrayedAll({
    foo(x) {
        return x + this.state.x; // error - property x does not exist on type {}
    }
})
```

Even creating an object of type `SingleArgFunctions` and then passing that to `makeArrayedAll` does not work:

```
const singleArgFunctions: SingleArgFunctions = {
    foo(x) {
        return this.state.x + x;
    }
}

const arrayedReturnFunctions4 = makeArrayedAll(singleArgFunctions); // error - IModel is not assignable to type MyModel
```

Why is the `Model` type not inferred as `MyModel` when using `makeArrayedAll`?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=78&ssc=1&pln=86&pc=68#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUiD29QFksATWAG1FROQGcqAoWqOJNDASQOLIG9bQ-Qq0ZHABcoLgF9aU2iFAAjarEKgskUMkhUA7glDQs+gBbgqoAI4BXWIPBrQR6NAAOVESEFoA1lgBuCRBIsbQA6VCwAW2BzYABWAE4ADnjYgAYAdgBGYABmdIAWHIAmRNkwSGDMS0hUaDstUG1wEjJ5DHksapUDUAiiUggtIRrYABoBQ0hYZX1DKmdYVHBEAE9jU1BnZHhkCNgmDTMOUnpoFYXQAGUoAHMSWABBeBuAMWra+oAeY7JYAA84JBCGZ2P0SOMHgA+UAAXlAAApoCY3PgweM-mIHgBKWHQh4AbloZwuTx2K2UACV9pZ4JA3jU6mpvmDQP9AcDQKDOBDoXDEcixD90ZicTC8QBtAC6hKJ5ww10gd0ez3pHzUAHl5AArRbQZmcVkA2BAkFC0APS6G9lmLDa3W88S8fjigDSg1AXlgKywiHNl0lYgVSqer3ejMg+tIEMurslkOkpzl5vgZMp1NpqvDmp1tUjvyNJs5ZotVuNHNtOegDp4-FArvdnu9votAeTqcIVOgNLpYa+xZjLrjCdoiF79giyE9pOQ5MIedLha5UfNkPhiEDt3uIczfbRK6xmJTM7TXYzY4jxehNf48HT6lHDPqCL+OOvtb4t9P6nFiDCyBa-KmOiWLSk6fBSDID5quoE5Tkes4PC085smWpp7iWKGFhW9rwmBmAokGW4que2a6nm0bxgebbHh2d47hqdq5v2V54eEQygLeVCWCQ0CwuIEiHNRs6dt29GQKRTHoZckIyrW8ISdAISNlQa5UDi1AIo2Pp+liUpYiE2DwAAomgRhruenxuphHJac20nwo2Yguq+eG1px3HQOKjaSnxsHKu2qleV6kpYoStYSFieGft2HE2B5hIyHI-y7M49yopw9CMAELD4CsPwLhyS7cHhniiI6778BioCQJYERtPAYX8BBmUwNl6BXJuyqho+ahmG+mBYFgG6KkR3XQd8eV7jVdUIPGMhZcw7XTsJdHnn1eHYENQknqJFl4JN3LVbV9UycOcioLewi3Bo8EzNFtJVD1DSEOAt61CQawbFgXigAAtIMVDgMQA2GEiGxGBpxIYPtPz0Gxgg3e2Ilnk9VCZIeSOrajfH9Zt8IvuVFWxV+dZ-KAADU6xUCEpWwCEfygeFZ1gBdsBXYqiM0cTMVQeGZjyGsqD-iQ11+ctMz2FAL2+EDlj-gInU3Tcj3QRoJBUIY31w71vHbJjX5iVQRQYzRyM9tjcK44NYhi7dhDmU9z4uUT3MPWTlNg9TtP0414GRYlYBGMEsD+PA4yWIDHO2+2iFkIQWA2NVWC8doOA-f9+UbFAiAILeKgaUV2vsXrptY9BVA5CbK0G2tvmTv5NGx-CVtYPjztE-d6ju1TNNCHAPt4RBkVlNVsDgEiejx4nrPs8rkdKkrKt8+ME-qFsNDXT00eNy0RcI-Po2G8NwbERbhN8HjBP9W5d49973d-L7oDNbQ8O63bZuG-kddwTHAEH11Q2oUgA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this looks like you're hoping the type of the variable `arrayedReturnFunctions` to which you're assigning the output of `makeArrayedAll()` will provide enough contextual typing for the input of `makeArrayedAll()` so that the input methods' `this` context will be inferred... but it's not happening.  I'm not exactly surprised that contextual inference would fail to happen in this scenario but I don't have a great answer about exactly why or how to force it to happen.

Right now my only suggestion is to note that type inference tends to work better in the "forward" direction; that is, a generic function's type parameters are easier to infer from the *input* to that function and not from the *expected output type* of the function.  And if that fails, you could always manually specify the generic type parameter.

Here's one way to manually specify the model type parameter and let the compiler infer the rest, using [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying):

```
const makeArrayedAllFor = <M extends IModel>() => <AS extends object>(
  fs: SingleArgFunctionObject<M, AS>) => makeArrayedAll(fs);

const arrayedReturnFunctions3: ArrayedReturnFunctions = makeArrayedAllFor<MyModel>()({
    foo(x) {
        return x + this.state.x;
    }
})

const arrayedReturnFunctions4 = makeArrayedAllFor<MyModel>()(singleArgFunctions);
```

This works now, although it's cumbersome.  That's the best I can think of at the moment; maybe someone has other ideas?  Oh well, good luck!

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/PTAEEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrUiD29QFksATWAG1FROQGcqAoWqOJNDASQOLIG9bQ-Qq0ZHABcoLgF9aU2iFAAjarEKgskUMkhUA7glDQs+gBbgqoAI4BXWIPBrQR6NAAOVESEFoA1lgBuCRBIsbQA6VCwAW2BzYABWAE4ADnjYgAYAdgBGYABmdIAWHIAmRNkwSGDMS0hUaDstUG1wEjJ5DHksapUDUAiiUggtIRrYABoBQ0hYZX1DKmdYVHBEAE9jU1BnZHhkCNgmDTMOUnpoFYXQAGUoAHMSWABBeBuAMWra+oAePFBYAA84JBCGZ2P0SOMHgA+UAAXlAAApoCY3Phxn8xA8AJSw6EPADctDOFyeOxWygASvtLPBIG8anU1N8wb8AbAgSDjuDQFDYQikaYxJy0RjsTDcQBtAC6BMJ5ww10gd0ezzpHzUAHl5AArRbQb4swHA0CgzgQy4GtlGrDa3XQuE8figcUAaUGoC8sBWWEQ3MukrECqVT1e7wZkG+Zpdksh0lOcu58FJFKpNNVYc1Otq+v+ho5YLNFvZqhttTt4l4-Bdbo9Xp9Dz9GMTyDJhEp0GptNDXzwked0djtEQXfsEWQHpJzeU2dZRZNpAhkPhiADt3uwbT3YXmMbSdbKc79M33OhDv48H3VUP9nhf2xp8dfHP7ZpTsQYWQLURyLRmOlFb4UgyIOw7qKO45Ni2DwtNOubGkKvqFlaJbQIu-6YCigZriqIEZrqEa+jG24JrubYdhuGrIfh9Ynmh4RDKA55UJYJDQLykiHMRk57s+B5qpAuFZj2BEyo68ICdAIQ1lQS5UNi1AIjW3q+piUqYiE2DwAAomgRhLiBoCfK6OaWmYil1pci41mIzp3mhjqMcx0DijWkq8mByq7jJzmepKmIEo6EiYmhT4dgxNiOQSQH0HI-y7M49z4GC9CMAELD4CsnKIXmnDlo6niiLlD58OioCQJYERtPA-n8IByUwKl6BXKuyohleDT3pgWBYCuipYa1fHfBl+aleVlUxjIKXMI1E4tqRqYgWYHXYN1nGzfu5HhngQ2miNFUIJCkXRWAqDnsItwaBBMwhS+Q5tWYhDgOetQkGsGxYF4oAALSDFQ4DEJ1hj8mYRjyUSGBbZy9B0YIF0ketC2ZDuXFzbxYZmPaaHLTetlFY+F7in8oAANTrFQIT5bAIR-H+AUDnIJ2wGdiqw1xYU8ZefFmPIayoB+JDne5M0zPYUAPb4f2WB+AjNRdNwc2GGgkFQhjvVDagw9scM8RtVBFEja3awtbGY11YiC5dhB6W1CK3oVRXXeohMk0D5NCHAVPVQBQVAdDrHm7uUEkC8OC8jBJlwWCi6itCnz1llxaZihMk9UG2FteJVEWdHvRjh5XGBzJflq-RmvI-Dd05PryaG3dbm50LhCB8H8CDZyUfwktXXY3bD4O6ATuk67wiU38nugIBQW0L70u9S1Osp31OvG46WO2x19kXi7FNU8T-dj7VU-q6xpcG2RC35HX4EBy0zet5H8KYvCv2z+uC1+UAA)

Comment: My intended usage of this was for type inference to occur from the expected output of the function, and works fine in the second example but not in the third. Type inference in the fourth example is in the forward direction, yet still fails. Your solution is actually reasonably workable - thanks. I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if there are any other ideas.